# the shell script is not printing values to file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am using a vasp script to print values to a summary file after runs in sub-folders. But it's coming out empty for me. What could be going wrong?
When I tried to run the jobs in the same folder then the file populated correctly. I checked the file from which I am fetching values and it has correct entries

```
rm WAVECAR
rm SUMMARY.fcc
for i in $(seq $1 $2 $3)
do
rm -r $i
mkdir $i
cd $i
cp ../INCAR .
cp ../POTCAR .
cp ../KPOINTS .
cp ../driver.sh .
cat >POSCAR <<!
fcc
$i
    0.0000000000    0.5000000000    0.5000000000
    0.5000000000    0.0000000000    0.5000000000
    0.5000000000    0.5000000000    0.0000000000
$4
1
Direct
   0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000
!
echo "a= $i" ;
sbatch --job-name=$(pwd) $5
V=$(awk '{for (I=1;I<=NF;I++) if ($I == "E0=") {print $(I+1)};}' OSZICAR);
E=$(echo $V | awk '{print $NF;}');
cd ..
echo $i $E >> SUMMARY.fcc
done
cat SUMMARY.fcc
```

Comment: Try running the script with `set -xv` to see what's going on.

Comment: That won't print anything as I am submitting jobs to a remote cluster using this. I tried. Specifically , this part could be a problem: 
echo "a= $i" ;
sbatch --job-name=$(pwd) $5
V=$(awk '{for (I=1;I<=NF;I++) if ($I == "E0=") {print $(I+1)};}' OSZICAR);
E=$(echo $V | awk '{print $NF;}');
cd ..
echo $i $E >> SUMMARY.fcc
done
cat SUMMARY.fcc

Comment: I wonder what vasp is.

Comment: Add your shebang and how do you run this script?

Comment: $5 is the script file name which I give as input. this has:

module load intel
module load mpich

mpirun -n 16 ~/bin/vasp_std > out